# MongoDB rs.initiate() query creates replica set without any Primary node

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'm creating a 3-nodes Replica set in MongoDB. When I launch the rs.initiate() query, it creates one node as a Secondary, while the other two remains in the "STARTUP" state.
In this situation, without any Primary, it is impossible to run any other query into the mongo shell and as a consequence I can't even reconfigure the replica set by deleting and adding later the other nodes.

I want to specify that I created this cluster cloning all the config files from another Replica Set that I created some months ago, and it works perfectly.

There is someone who faced this issue and know how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't it an oplog problem ?

Comment: If you could edit the output of `rs.status()` and `rs.conf()` into your answer, that would help a lot.

Comment: Review mongod logs on all nodes, they probably will provide clues as to what each node is doing and where the problem is.

Comment: Now I can't post any output because everytime I run a logoff from the shell, it cancels any rreplica set configuration.
Now I'm retrying to do the rs.initiate query but I got a network issue with the first node, which seems unreachable.
That is very strange, considering that it is listening on the right port and there is no firewall that could block the connections.

Anyway, I'm going to restore all the nodes from snapshots at the moment before installing MongoDB, and re-do the installation from zero. Probably some .conf files have been pasted dirty in the previous installation.

Comment: UPDATE
After perform a "iptables --flush", the rs.initiate query worked!
In the first place it created the Replica Set with all the three nodes as Secondary, but after a while, one of them become Primary and now it works fine.